# Is it possible to create your own custom locale

Tags: c++, locale

Since Windows doesnt have a C++ locale with UTF8 support by default, i would like to construct a custom locale object which supports UTF8 (by creating it with a custom ctype facet).

**How can i construct a locale object with a my own ctype implementation** (i only found functions to construct a locale using an already existing locale as base..)

If C++ does not support construction of locales with a custom ctype facet at all, why is that so ?

Comment: ctype is not compatible with variable length encodings like utf-8. For example, tolower() takes and returns a single CharType. Any character outside the ASCII subset will thus be untranslatable by ctype.

Comment: See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html. Also Stroustrup Appendix D, http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_loc.pdf. And Standard C++ IOStreams and locales http://books.google.fr/books?id=nnRog4I-3jwC

Comment: @eric: damn, forgot about that (damn the designers of ctype, not taking variable length encodings like UTF8 into account)... +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to create custom facets by inheriting from std::locale::facet. Locales can use those custom facets as in following code:

```
class custom_facet : public std::locale::facet {
public:
    static std::locale::id id;
    custom_facet(int);  
    int custom_value() const; 
    };

std::locale  custom_locale ( std::locale(), new custom_facet() );
int s = std::use_facet<custom_facet>(custom_locale).custom_value();
```

Comment: accepted as answer, even though this answered my question only partially, but annos links helped me aswell, so this question is solved for me.